# Dynamically change API endpoints in AngularJs based on the URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

How can I dynamically change API endpoints in AngularJs based on the URL typed or changed or appended in the search bar?

**Example**, if I had a path that is `https://whatever.com/card-mca`, I would like to update the end of the API paths to include the end of the URL (this is the name of a dashboard, and also the API parameter to call the correct API).

**This is an example of my API endpoints:**

```
const metaDataURL = 'api/metadata/card-mca';
const frequencyDataURL = 'api/frequencies/card-mca';
const testingDataURL = 'api/testing/card-mca';
const securityDataURL = 'api/securities/card-mca';
const qualityDataURL = 'api/quality/card-mca';
```

So if I changed (by typing) my URL to `https://whatever.com/foo-mca`, I would like my API endpoints to be updated to the following:

```
const metaDataURL = 'api/metadata/foo-mca';
const frequencyDataURL = 'api/frequencies/foo-mca';
const testingDataURL = 'api/testing/foo-mca';
const securityDataURL = 'api/securities/foo-mca';
const qualityDataURL = 'api/quality/foo-mca';
```

**Note:** I am using **ui-router** and was wondering if one would **use an event** such as `$rootScope.$on`, and how would one implement this?

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // transitionTo() promise will be rejected with 
        // a 'transition prevented' error
    })
```

My API paths are in my single controller. I also have a single view, and no navigation. The idea is to change the dashboard that gets displayed by changing the URL and the API endpoints. That way the app stay DRY and I can use a single controller and view.

Comment: So, you want your constants to not be constant?

Comment: @Araymer that is correct

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Look up the spot about parameters. I think that's exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Araymer Thanks for the link. I actually checked it out before I posted the question. I did find what seems to be a working solution. I am not on the VPN at the moment, so will only know tomorrow. Will then post my solution. Thanks!

Comment: Changing URL may mean you are about to load a completely new dashboard. Your application should now contain all new set of Endpoints. If it is your http service, then, you can decide just before calling it. https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_services.asp Get the value of URLs through a function that decides which APIs to use.